# Animation will not work after app reappears from background

Tags: ios, swift

I call a few animations in viewWillAppear. The animations will only be triggered when the app launches the very first time. When I hide (not close the app) the app and reopen it, all of the animations will look like they have completed their actions. This also happens when I call the animations in viewDidLoad. I want the animations to start over again each time I open the app even if I don't close it.

Attached is an example code of an animation I made.

```
func animateFlowerOne(){


    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut

    //Flower 1
    let flowers = UIImageView()
    flowers.image = UIImage(named: "flower-face")
    flowers.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 380, width: 0, height: 0)
    self.view.addSubview(flowers)


    UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, delay: 2.0, options: options, animations: {
        flowers.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 380, width: 15, height: 15)
        }, completion: { animationFinished in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, delay: 2.0, options: options, animations: {
                flowers.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 380, width: 0, height: 0)

                }, completion: { animationFinished in
                    flowers.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.animateFlowerOne()
            })
    })
}
```

Here is how everything looks in viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


    audioPlayers()
    movingClouds()
    animateFlowers()
    animateFlowerOne()
    flyingPlane()
    balloon()
    hotAirBalloon()

}
```

Anyone has any idea why it is not restarting after I unhide the app ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how it works: `viewWillAppear:` is not called when you resume an app.

What you should do to solve this is registering your controller with the default notification centre for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification. In the handler method you can run the animation.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
  self,
  selector: "cameBackFromSleep:",
  name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
  object: nil
)

func cameBackFromSleep(sender : AnyObject) {

   [self viewWillAppear:true];      
}
```

Do not forget to remove the observer in the `deinit` method.

BTW, calling `viewWillAppear` as I do is just a shortcut. You better define a common method that both `viewWillAppear:` and `cameBackFromSleep:` call.